# Magento CE 2.2.X Configurable product with 1 Attribute -Error: Display Out of Stock Products

Tags: attributes, magento2.2, out-of-stock

**Steps to reproduce**

Install Magento 2.2.X CE Sample Data
Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > Display Out of Stock Products = Yes.

CLI php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Admin > Products > Catalog > Create configurable product with 1 attribute. Set either Quantity = 0 or Stock Status = Out of Stock.

**Expected result**

Frontend product should display with all Simple products part of Configurable product and should display with class disabled (red strike through) for out of stock .

**Actual result**

Frontend product not displayed all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento bug, file an issue if you haven't done that already. Current workaround is **Keeping stock status as In stock** and [use a module](https://magenticians.com/magento-2-disable-add-to-cart-button/) to **disable and replace text on Add to Cart button** for the configurable product ( i.e replace with "Out of stock" ).